# Selenium Java -> Find Elements Nofitication banner visible only for milliseconds

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I have dynamic notification banner in Web application , which will be visible for milliseconds ,How can i identify the notification banner in Selenium Web Driver using Java

Comment: I have valid Xpath, when u use $x <path> notification banner is recognized correctly

Comment: Please edit your question to provide additional information, instead of commenting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an explicit wait. If the banner is shown within that explicit wait and you use the isDisplayed function, you can determine if it was displayed with a simple boolean.